# sending http GET request but receiving no result

Tags: android, rest, http

I have a website running with woocommerce and i try to retrieve the products through a http get request.
When I try the url on postman or on my web browser everything works just fine. However, on my android app I get no result back.

Someone no what's wrong?

Here's my code:

```
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.httpRequest(url,"GET",params);

public JSONObject httpRequest(String url, String method, ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> params) throws SocketTimeoutException{
    String response = "";

    try {
        URL url_o = new URL(url);
        this.connection = (HttpURLConnection) url_o.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter(params.get(i).first, params.get(i).second);
        }
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        if(query!=null){
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
            bufferedWriter.write(query);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        }

        connection.connect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        if(e.getMessage().equals("connect timed out"))
           throw new SocketTimeoutException();
        else
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line = null;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

            response = stringBuilder.toString();

            connection.disconnect();
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        json = new JSONObject(response);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

Knowing that the url has been build by postman with the consumer key and secret and other parameters.

The httpRequest is working just fine as I used it several times to get php scripts results.

At the end of the httRequest function the var response is empty.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: no exception in logcat? What is inside responseCode variable?

Comment: @an_droid_dev No exception exept JSONException at the end of the function due to an emty response string while creating JSONObject.
And the responseCode variable is 200

Comment: Well, try remove doOutput from GET requests, those are intended to POST

Comment: You should be using a Networking Library such as this: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ or any other. Please don't write networking code yourself unless absolutely necessary

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos nailed it. Thanks man.
Thanks to everyone as well for helping

Comment: @OTmn ty, i added as an answer, if you have time please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove doOutput from GET requests, those are intended to POST